# Tabulator paging footer on top

Tags: tabulator

In Tabulator, paging footer is normally at the bottom of the table.
Is there any way to put it on the top of the table?

Since my page contains something like 300 lines, and only paging can be done after long scroll-down.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, you can use `Custom Pagination Control Element` to do this I suppose.

By default the pagination controls are added to the footer of the table. If you wish the controls to be created in another element pass a DOM node or a CSS selector for that element to the `paginationElement` option.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    pagination:true,
    paginationElement:paginationElement, //build pagination controls in this element
});
```

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/tabulator-test-forked-96vfge

Hope it helps!